# When appending to the end of the XML, the formatOutput doesn't work but when first creating the file, the formatOutput works fine

Tags: php, xml

This may sound pretty basic but right now I am very confused.

Right now I'm using php to create an XML file, first I check if the file exists, and if he doesn't I create the file with the first entry created, but if the XML file does already exist, then ill will just append the data. The data is being appended when needed and the file is being created without any bugs, but the only small problem I am having is that when I append the data to the end of the file, it won't format to regular waterfall format it has, instead it just appends it in one line. Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id_from'];
$id_to = $_POST['userid_to'];
$content = $_POST['message'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$filename = 'chats/'.$id.'-'.$id_to.'.xml';

if(file_exists($filename)){
    $xml->load($filename);

    $messages = $xml->getElementsByTagName('messages')->item(0);

    $message = $xml->createElement("message");
    $messages->appendChild($message);

    $content = $xml->createElement("content", $content);
    $message->appendChild($content);

    $to = $xml->createElement("to", $id_to);
    $message->appendChild($to);

    $from = $xml->createElement("from", $id);
    $message->appendChild($from);

}else{
    //creating root
    $messages = $xml->createElement('messages');
    $xml->appendChild($messages);

    $message = $xml->createElement("message");
    $messages->appendChild($message);

    $content = $xml->createElement("content", $content);
    $message->appendChild($content);

    $to = $xml->createElement("to", $id_to);
    $message->appendChild($to);

    $from = $xml->createElement("from", $id);
    $message->appendChild($from);
}
$xml->save($filename) or die("error");


 ?>
```

And below is a picture of my xml file.

Thank you very much!

[Image of my xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfDUQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disabled whitespaces preservation before loading the file, so DOMDocument can do its own business without trying to keep the original format in place.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false ;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
```